# rebuild c# project for linux

Tags: c#, linux, wpf, mono

We have made a wpf .Net application. The application was developed for window 7, but it also works with windows 8 and 8.1, uses .net framework 4.5.2 and saves data to windows server 2012 r2. 
Now our cheif (after he has spoken with sales managers) wants to run this program on Linux based system(it will be cheaper).
I have read a little bit about Mono. But did not use it yet.

**I would like to know:**

1. if it is in general a good idea to transform application developed to work with windows to cross-platform?
2. Will it work stable as it would work only by windows?
3. Should we also change database, or it will work with windows server 2012 r2?

Comment: I dont think wpf implementations on linux are mature for production...

Comment: @j-p thank you, you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no expert here, and have never done this myself. I do believe you will be able to use at least some of the current codebase, but will need to re-factor a good chunk of it. Mono is quite stable, and works well but I would not expect to work *as well* as Windows. As for the database, as long as Mono has no limitations (which I doubt it does) you should be fine with Windows server. Also I doubt you will be able to use *all* of your codebase across both platforms, and may have to have at least some platform specific code.